# Spontaneous symmetry breaking and ergodicity

Tags: symmetry-breaking, ising-model, ergodicity

I am studying the spontaneous symmetry breaking in the mean-field Ising model and it's clear to me the necessity of taking first the thermodynamic limit and then the zero-field limit to see the phase transition, otherwise we only see zero magnetisation even under Tc. I was wondering if there was a phase space approach underlying this result and if the spontaneous symmetry breaking implied and ergodicity breaking as well, as I imagine that the ensemble average is anyway zero, but this is not what we observe physically. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Please clarify a dimensionality of problem, write equations related to your concerns. For Ising model in $D>2$ dimensions you can start easily from the model *without* external field and capture the phase transition. Thermodynamic limit appears due to Lee-Yang theorem (Lee-Yang zeros). When you write down the partition function you already imply that ergodicity takes place. Please clarify how do you relate ergodicity and phase transition or provide some refs.